# Insert new row and get it's id mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I got two tables in mysql database one is `users` and second is `user_lvl` when inserting new user i want to insert new row in `user_lvl` table, column `user_id`. The value i want to get from just registred user is it's `id`. Well getting last inserted row is't the problem. I am just thinking what if two user registers at the same time? Is it possible, that i will get others users id? Or there is better way to get `id` from row just inserted?

Comment: The way MySQL works you don't have that issue.  The insert ID is connection specific, so two concurrent connections won't give out the same ID for an auto-increment field.

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger to insert a new record for every new user

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER insert_lvl AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    insert into user_lvl (user_id)
    select new.id;
END
|
delimiter ;
```